# Neo4j Cypher Match all

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is the following schema:

```
Person-[:HAS]->(:Skill)<-[:REQUIRES]-(:Job)
```

`Job` requires some number of `Skills`. How to properly with Cypher `MATCH` `Person` which has `ALL` of the `Skills` required by some certain `Job`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, here we collect skills of the job and the person skills in different collections and then we check if all the skills for the job, are present in the persons skill collection:

```
MATCH (j:Job)-[:REQUIRES]->(s:Skill)
WITH j, collect(DISTINCT s) AS skillsRequiredForTheJob
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS]->(s:Skill)
WITH j, p, skillsRequiredForTheJob, collect(DISTINCT s) AS personSkills
WHERE ALL(skill IN skillsRequiredForTheJob WHERE skill IN personSkills)
RETURN p
```