# Neo4j Cypher and node properties access

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have statistical nodes with pre-aggregated data that can sometimes have 50-100k properties each. I realize it's crazy and smells bad, but it's the best I've got in my struggle with optimizing performance for my business needs.

I have implemented the following filtering logic on such nodes (`childD`):

```
WHERE apoc.coll.containsAllSorted($profileDetailedCriterionIds, childD.detailedCriterionIds) 
UNWIND childD.detailedCriterionIds AS mCId 
WITH childD, mCId 

WHERE 
(childD['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + mCId] = 0 OR childD['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + mCId] <= $profileCriterionAvgVoteWeights[toString(mCId)]) 
AND (childD['criterionExperienceMonths.' + mCId] = 0 OR childD['criterionExperienceMonths.' + mCId] <= $profileCriterionExperienceMonths[toString(mCId)]) 

WITH DISTINCT childD
```

As you may see, for each `mCId` there is a pre-aggregated  property which I access by its name.

So, my question is about underlying implementation of Neo4j node properties. Are they stored in some key-value storage? Can I assume that they will always be accessed with the same time when I refer to them by their exact name (as in my query above), regardless of the number of properties in the node?

**UPDATED**

```
MATCH (childD)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(pc:Criterion)
WHERE pc.id IN $vacancyDetailedCriterionIds
WITH childD, collect(DISTINCT pc.id) as profileCriterionIds
WHERE size(profileCriterionIds) >= size($vacancyDetailedCriterionIds)

WITH childD
MATCH (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childDStat:JobableStatistic)

UNWIND $vacancyDetailedCriterionIds AS mCId
WITH childD, childDStat, mCId

WHERE 
($vacancyCriterionAvgVoteWeights[toString(mCId)] = 0 OR $vacancyCriterionAvgVoteWeights[toString(mCId)] <= childDStat['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + mCId])
AND 
($vacancyCriterionExperienceMonths[toString(mCId)] = 0 OR $vacancyCriterionExperienceMonths[toString(mCId)] <= childDStat['criterionExperienceMonths.' + mCId])
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking from the [article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-data-on-disk/#:%7E:text=Properties%20are%20stored%20as%20a,its%20start%20and%20end%20node.):

```
Data stored on disk is all linked lists of fixed size records. 
Properties are stored as a linked list of property records, each holding a key and value 
and pointing to the next property. Each node and relationship references its first property 
record. The Nodes also reference the first relationship in its relationship chain.
Each Relationship references its start and end node. 
It also references the previous and next relationship record for the start and end node 
respectively.
```

This means that the time to access a property will remain same if it's position is same in the linked list.
Now, during deletion of a property access time might decrease, as some elements will get shifted.
During insertions, as far as I know, the insertions happen at the end of the list, so yess the position of a particular property remains same only hence, the time will be constant to access it.

You can ckeck for insertions yourself, try these queries, and the see the properties of the node, they come in the order they were inserted:

```
MATCH (s:Sample) set s.a = 2 return s
MATCH (s:Sample) set s.b = 2 return s
MATCH (s:Sample) set s.c = 2 return s
```

In short, access time for a property will depend on its position in the linked list, so different properties will have different access times. But for a property, the access time across multiple runs of the query will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your support, as always! I have additional question - am I going crazy with such approach with such super nodes with thousands of properties? Or it may work?

Comment: otherwise I'll have to collect this information (collections) dynamically like you suggested there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349673/neo4j-cypher-match-all which potentially may take additional resources and time. What do you think?

Comment: It may seem to work in the short run, but it is not something that will scale with time. Just take a simple example right, even with 1k nodes with 1k properties, a query might traverse 1M properties, which won't be as performant.  On the other hand, the way of collections which I suggested, may help in better performance, since I am not accessing any property there in the query. You can try profiling both versions of the query to see which performs better. Also, if possible try refactoring the graph, so that the super nodes can be break down into easily manageable small nodes.

Comment: Thanks! As you suggested, I have updated my query logic to use nodes on the initial `MATCH` (instead of the full-scan with `APOC` `containsAllSorted`), as you may see from the updated question. But I still use node properties for filtering logic. I have all of these data in the nodes (best practice Neo4j schema design), but looks like filtering works better on the pre-aggregated node properties (maybe because of no JOINs). And I'm really surprised that Neo4j uses `List` for properties access instead of the `Map`. Do we have any reasons for that?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but I problem I can think with maps is collisions. Which will be hard to deal with at the disk level, I believe. With lists we don't have these problems